# Automatically keeping track of attributes' values

Tags: python

Let's say I have a class defined by :

```
class Wall(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
```

I would like to keep track automatically of color transitions.
That is , if I instanciate my class as follows :

```
wall = Wall('red')
```

and then change color :

```
wall.color = 'green'
```

I would like to automatically get a list

```
['green', 'red']
```

created, in a way that if I continue as:

```
wall.color = ['yellow']
```

I obtain the list :

```
['yellow', 'green']
```

and so on.

What I have tried so far does not work :

```
class Wall(object):

def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color
    self._last_two_colors = [self.color, None]

def change_color(self, color):
    self._last_two_colors[1] = self._last_two_colors[0]
    self._last_two_colors[0] = self.color
    return self._last_two_colors
```

My initial version, not working unfortunately :

```
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, color):
        self._last_two_colors = []
        self.color = color

    @property
    def last_two_colors(self):
        return self._last_two_colors

    @last_two_colors.setter
    def last_two_colors(self):
        self._last_two_colors = [self.color]+self._last_two_colors
        self._last_two_colors = self._last_two_colors[:2]
        return self._last_two_colors
```

It should be noted that I do not wish to call the method change_color , it would have to be called automatically whenever the color is updated. 
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you not just need a `self.color = color` at the top of your `change_color()` method?

Comment: Make color a property (@property decortaor or with the property builtin) and define getter and setter accordingly to your needs.

Comment: I actually have a doubt on what change_color arguments should be. Maybe just self ? None of then work, however, nor adding self.color =color, as you suggested.

Comment: If you never call the method nothing will change.

Comment: I had tried a @property decorator as well (see edit), but I don't seem to find the solution

Comment: When you want something to happen when you type `wall.color = 'green'`, you need to define the setter for `color`, not for `last_two_colors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like described in my comment, here's a first non-perfect version:

```
In [14]: class Wall(object):
...: 
...:     def __init__(self, color):
...:         self.__last_two = [color, color]
...:         self.__color = color
...:     
...:     @property
...:     def color(self):
...:         return self.__color
...:     
...:     @color.setter
...:     def color(self, new_val):
...:         self.__color = new_val
...:         self.__last_two.pop(0)
...:         self.__last_two.append(new_val)
...:         print(self.__last_two)
...:  

In [15]: x = Wall(1)

In [16]: x.color
Out[16]: 1

In [17]: x.color = 2
[1, 2]

In [18]: x.color = 3
[2, 3]

In [19]: x.color = 4
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually modified it as follows:           self._last_two = [new_val]+self._last_two  - changing the attribute names as starting with _ and not __ , since I need then to be easily accessible.

Comment: Actually, if you look at `In[16]` and all the following lines, you can implement this "easy access" with properties ;-)

Comment: `self._last_two = [new_val]+self._last_two` will not remove the 3rd value

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [property()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

```
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, color):
        self._color = color
        self._color_transitions = [color]

    @property
    def color(self):
        """I'm the 'color' property."""
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        if len(self._color_transitions) > 1:
            self._color_transitions.pop(0)
        self._color_transitions.append(value)
        self._color = value

    @property
    def color_transitions:
        return self._color_transitions
```

Comment: The length of the transisitons list will always be 1, but it should be 2.

Comment: This actually makes a bit more sense than my solution because I pretend to have a transition when there never was one (but I'm lazy and just wrote that my solution is not perfect :D). You could top that if you add a check for the length in the getter for `color_transitions` and return `None` if the length is 1 (and therefore there never was a color transition, assuming nobody changed `color_transitions` manually which is the reason why I recommend using two underscores...). Also, one might change the name `color_transitions` now that you changed your implementation.